# Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer identify consumer

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, jms, spring-jms

We are using `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` (`DMLC`) in our JMS application, we put concurrency as 5.
Is there a unique way to identify each consumer like?

```
DMLC1Consumer1
DMLC1Consumer2
DMLC1Consumer3
DMLC1Consumer4
DMLC1Consumer5
```

Comment: The 5 threads running in the container have unique names. What else do you mean?

Comment: which method on dmlc container will get those unique names?

Comment: There is no method but you can capture the thread name in your listener. `Thread.currentThread().getName()`.

Comment: why do you care about what threads are doing what?  if you're concerned about message ordering (and potentially processing messages out of order) you shouldn't be concurrent

Comment: its not about ordering, but who is doing what, need some stats. thanks.